# What is the origin of the River Citarum on Java, Indonesia?

Tags: geography, rivers

The Citarum river seems to pass through Bandung. The [Cikapundung River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cikapundung_River) seems to empty into the Citarum, but this means Citarum starts somewhere else, right?

[image: Citarum]

I tried to follow it in a map. It seems to end in the sea and pass a national park (Cagar Alam Gunung Tangkuban Perahu) in between, but where does it actually start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Citarum River](http://citarum.org/en/about-us/citarum-facts.html),

> originates in Situ Cisanti located at the foot of Mount Wayang, which lies to the south of the city of Bandung, and travels to the north until it empties into the Java Sea.

[Situ Cisanti](https://www.bandung-guide.com/2017/11/situ-cisanti-hidden-lake.html) is a artificial lake, about 5 to 10 ha in size, depending on which sources one reads. It is fed by [seven springs:](https://travelingyuk.com/situ-cisanti/188674/?utm_source=idle&utm_medium=dekstop&utm_campaign=reload) Citarum, Cikoleberes, Cikahuripan, Cihaniwung, Cisadane, Cikawudukan, and Cisanti springs.

The picture below shows the designated origin of the Citarum River.

[image]

Aerial view of the lake.

[image]